# repeat non-null value in Pandas DataFrame with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to fill all NaN values with a non-NaN value using groupby. I know I can do this using fillna(method='ffill') and then fillna(method='bfill') since my non-NaN value is not always a the beginning or end, or I can create a new DataFrame with the non-NaN value and then merge them, but I need to do this a bunch of times and I was wondering if there is a more efficient method to reduce the process time.

I was thinking something like a .transform(fillna) function.

This is my input:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Nan |
| A | Nan |
| A | 'apples' |
| B | Nan |
| B | 'bananas' |
| B | Nan |

and this is what I'd like to get

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 'apples' |
| A | 'apples |
| A | 'apples' |
| B | 'bananas |
| B | 'bananas' |
| B | 'bananas' |

Comment: `df.groupby('col1')['col2'].bfill().ffill()`

Comment: thank you, it's so simple I'm ashamed of not thinking of it.

Answer (score 1):

As envisioned, you can do:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].ffill().bfill()
```

You can also do:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('first')
```

which should be faster on large dataframes.

*Note that it is doing the same thing in this case but **it would behave differently if you have non unique non-NaN values in each group.***

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.col2 = df1.col2.mask((df1.col2.isnull()) & (df1.col1 == 'A'), 'apples')
df1.col2 = df1.col2.mask((df1.col2.isnull()) & (df1.col1 == 'B'), 'bananas')
```